# 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender (office365)

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app, office365-apps

I m trying to send email with following configuration

- Host: `smtp.office365.com`
- port: 587
- user: `myemail@example.com`
- pass: "mypassword"

I'm getting the following exception:

> 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

I have gone through many forums that told me to set send as permission for the mailbox but I m not able to find any such configuration in Outlook web app, or do I need to configure it somewhere else and if it so then where? I have only used above configuration for sending mails and have not done any config with outlook web app. What all I need to change and configure in my outlook web app?

Answer (score 60):

Beware that this error might also occur when the `from` email does not match the `username`.

So, be sure to test the value `myemail@example.com` is the same on `user` and `from`.

If it works when both fields have the same value and doesn't work when the from is different from the user, it means you should contact the company responsible for the email server and ask them to create a shared account and add `SendAs` priviledges for the account.

Comment: This was the issue with me.

Comment: thanks lot it's work for me @So, be sure to test the value myemail@domain.com is the same on user and from.

Comment: This works. I was not providing To and From properly.

Comment: Your answer helped me. I had the same case of different "from" and "user" parameter. +1

Comment: I do not know why this must be set to match - as from fields are simply that and have nothing to do with the authenticated user. If you can authenticate - who cares what name is in the from field. I know not your issue just my rant. If I want to spam with the authenticated user ok , if I want to with 50 million other names same difference - I have access and can send emails. The authenticated user is what should count!

Answer (score 6):

go the the Exchange management console and select the user. Right Click, go to the send as permissions option.. check that User NT AUTHORITY\SELF is listed. If not add it.

Comment: I also have this issue, although not with office365, but would this approach work on a wider issue of sending from a mailserver address?

Answer (score 3):

Answer provided by Luis Cruz is the right one.. However, I will try to be more descriptive though,

We were trying to send mail in Mantis Bug Tracker through Office 365 account and were facing the same issue. Below was the config,

```
$g_enable_email_notification = ON;
$g_phpMailer_method          = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host                 = 'smtp.office365.com';
$g_smtp_username             = 'abc@example.com';
$g_smtp_password             = '****';
$g_smtp_connection_mode      = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port                 = 587;
```

Clearly what we were missing was the 'from' property. Adding following properties resolved the issue,

```
$g_from_name               = 'Mantis Admin';
$g_from_email              = 'abc@example.com';
$g_return_path_email       = 'abc@example.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange PowerShell, add the Send As permission so that Domain\jsmith can send as `myemail@example.com` (example):

```
Add-ADPermission "myemail@example.com" -User "Domain\jsmith" -Extendedrights "Send As"
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reason for this issue, One of this is which is most frequently comes because

Login name and From address is not same.

Login = 'abc@gmailcom'
FROM = 'abc@gmailcom'

Now use these variables, It will work.