# Laravel sending email with Office 365 Email

Tags: laravel-5, office365

We've changed from gmail to office 365, but the issue: `Client does not have permissions to send as this sender` 550 when sending email.

Do we have any configuration in office 365 mail service to enable sending email from website/application?

This is my `.env` configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=mail_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure the correct `from` email address, that matches to your Office 365 Email Address.

You can configure it in **config/mail.php** `from` option or these env variables `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` and `MAIL_FROM_NAME`.

See also: [550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender (office365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357440/550-5-7-1-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender-office365)