# Laravel 5.4 and office365 company email

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use my company office365 email to send email from laravel 5.4.

So I edit my .env like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=domaine-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@domaine.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@domaine.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=WebsiteName
```

I started with default laravel auth system. When I fill the input with email on my database and click send, I've got a success message :

> We have e-mailed your password reset link!

But I've got nothing on my email, nothing on my spam or everywhere else.

Did I miss a step ?

Thank for your help

Comment: MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: Still nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your settings are correct there?

I think you should be using port 587 for SMTP for Office 365.

EDIT

Check out this answer also, which has more information: [Laravel sending email with Office 365 Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645176/laravel-sending-email-with-office-365-email)

There is bound to be a small part of your config not set correctly, and it's hard to tell which part, as you've obfuscated the real data (understandably).

Comment: That's definitely the correct port, so we've already fixed part of the issue there. I'll update my answer with further information.

Comment: As I want to use my office domain to send email with office365, it's normal to use domaine-com.mail.protection.outlook.com instead of smtp ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this Mail-Driver:
https://github.com/motze92/office365-mail

This send's email from the Graph Rest Api and works better than the Office365 SMTP what gives many times unexpected timeouts and errors.