# Laravel SMTP - fwrite(): SSL: The operation completed successfully

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, swiftmailer

### **Using laravel 5.7 with SwiftMailer library (SMTP to office365)**

---

I have done my fair share of research and have not come across a problem like this. There are errors that I've seen and that were somewhat like this one, but they all made sens to me unlike this one.

I have no clue how to fix this and would love a second hand on this.

---

**Error return:**

> fwrite(): SSL: The operation completed successfully.

---

**config/mail.php** has all the configuration as it should be:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.office365.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),                               //office 365 need to use 587
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),                 //office 365 need to use TLS
'username' => env('xxxx@xxxxxxx.xx'),
'password' => env('xxxxxxxxx'),
```

---

**.env** also has its configuration sorted out correctly:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587                                                  //office 365 need to use 587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@xxxxxxx.xx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls                                            //office 365 need to use TLS
```

---

postContact function in **Controller**

```
public function postContact(Request $request) {

//validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'companyName' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'min:10']);

//request data from submitted form
    $data = array(
        'companyName' => $request->companyName,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
    );

//send mail
    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        //$message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('xxxx@xxxxxxx.xx');
        $message->subject('New email from xxxxxxxx');
    });

    return redirect('/');    }
```

---

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: @VaggelisKsps 7.2.5

Comment: Do you have the same problem for example with mailtrap? If not it is probably some kind of restrictions or configuration of the office365. It may need an ssl on your website to determine that the connection is secure. It doesn't look like a laravel error but check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645176/laravel-sending-email-with-office-365-email?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This does not happen with mailtrap, I was converting from development to live (so had to change mail server). Needing a ssl on your website seems unlikely to me if the mailserver credentials are correct. Where does one check the configurations of office365's smtp?

Comment: Does the email is sent at all? According to microsoft docs Error success means that you don't have any error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: No the emails don't send, thats the whole reason im making this post.....

Comment: Hi @Tomm, did you find a solution?

Comment: @StanleyUmeanozie I have had a friend of mine run my code for me which all worked, so there was nothing wrong with the code. Then after some googling I came to the conclusion of reinstalling xampp (since the mail servers seemed to interupt weaith eachother).